vim + dos fileformat + Reading or writing extended attribute error
Trying to edit a file using vim (VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1) from gitbash utility
I do have the following settings for fileformat (ff) to unix
$ cat ~/.vimrc
set t_vb=
set ts=4
set fileformat=unix

Despite that, whenever file is opened as
vi requirements.txt

I get the following error
requirements.txt[+] [dos] (01:09 07/06/2024)                                                                           3,2 All
"requirements.txt"
E1509: Error occurred when reading or writing extended attribute
"requirements.txt" [dos] 14L, 275B written
Press ENTER or type command to continue

vim is trying to open the file in dos, which should be in unix format and then there is an error E1509: Error occurred when reading or writing extended attribute
There is no special attribute for the file requirements.txt
$ ls -lrt requirements.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc 103 273 Jun  7 01:09 requirements.txt

Any pointers?

is it related to https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/13246  ?

File format is set automatically (your vimrc setting is doing nothing). So if it says "dos" then it's dos. It works just how it should.
